# How can I open and display permanently the windows "sound control" shown in the picture?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Deezer for listening to Music. I just found out that when using my Keyboard 'FN'-keys to adjust the volume a window appears which shows the current volume and also have the possibility in here to skip the current song or pause without having to re-open deezer:

[image]

Does anyone know how this Little "Program" is called and how I can set some Option for this or use a different shortcut? And more important can I somehow snap of the Right pane with the skip/pause function and Display this permanently somewhere on my Desktop?

Comment: Are you using Spotify?

Comment: No, I am using Deezer

Answer (score 0):

This is the new On Screen Display (OSD) of Windows 10, rather than a part of Spotify.
Once the OSD only included the volume, but it has now been extended.
It is activated by using the media keys and stays on the screen for some prescribed time.
I don't know of any customization that can be applied to it, except its timeout.

The timeout can be changed via
Control Panel > Ease of Access > Ease of Access Center > Make it easier to focus on tasks,
and is called "How long should Windows notification dialog boxes stay open".

It may may be easier to set it in the registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility`, item `MessageDuration`,
containing the timeout in seconds.

This setting will also affect the timeout of some other Windows messages.